# How to write connected relation $\mathcal{R}$ in terms of set notation only.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations

*Definition: A relation $\mathcal{R}$ on set $X$ is called connected if for all $x,y\in X,\;$$x\mathcal{R} y$ or $y\mathcal{R} x$ or $x=y$*

Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a connected relation on set $X$ and set $Y$, and write $\mathcal{R}$ only in terms of set notation.

I know that relation $\mathcal{R}$ is a subset of the cartesian product of $X\times Y$, but I have no idea how to precisely capture the $\color{red}{\text{connected}\;\mathcal{R} }$

The general set notation of relation I familiar with is  $\mathcal{R}\subseteq X\times Y=\{(x,y):  x\in X, y\in Y\}$

Please help

Comment: This doesn't make sense, your definition of connected applies to relations on a single set, how is it supposed to extend to a relation between two potentially distinct sets? Another issue is that a connected relation as you defined it in the first paragraph is not unique, there could be many such relations on a set. So you can't write "a connected relation" in set builder notation, without knowing what exactly the relation is, unless you are really asking for an example of a connected relation?

Comment: @Carlyle Thank you for your reply. I think the definition defined on a singleton set can be considered a relation as a subset of $X\times X$, now changing $X$ into another distinct $Y$ should be fine. I am not asking for an example of connected relation.

Comment: Your final line is not correct: a relation $\mathcal R$ from $X$ to $Y$ is defined to be a **subset** of $X \times Y$, not *the entire set $X \times Y$* as you have written it. Hence a relation on $X$ is a subset of $X \times X$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for your reply. I do not mean $\forall x\in X,\;\forall y\in Y$

Comment: @LeeMosher Yes, you are right. My final line seems implicitlty say it is for all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me preface my answer by correcting what might be a misconception of the OP, or at the very least a "mis-expression". The definition of *a connected relation on $X$* requires a ***relation on $X$***. So before one can even speak sensibly about connectivity of a relation between two sets $X$ and $Y$, one requires that $X=Y$. In fact the concept of a connected relation between two unequal sets is not defined.

With that in mind, you can easily do this ***if*** you make use of some standard notation:

- Cartesian product notation $X \times X$
- The diagonal subset $\Delta = \{(x,x) \mid x \in X\}$
- The inversion operator: $\mathcal R^{-1} = \{(x,y) \in X \times X \mid (y,x) \in \mathcal R \}$

It follows that $\mathcal R$ is connected if and only if
$$\mathcal R \cup \mathcal R^{-1} \cup \Delta = X \times X
$$

Comment: I think you also want the union with the diagonal, to account for "or $x=y$".

Comment: Ah, good point, I'll fix that.

Comment: another short question: Not sure if connected relation can imply itself reflexive? I don't think it can.

Comment: That's exactly why @MeesdeVries suggested the correction to my answer: by taking the union with the diagonal, the relation becomes reflexive.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but I'm still not sure what the question is asking, since they're seemingly talking about connected relations relating elements from potentially distinct sets, and this only addresses the case where these sets are equal

Comment: I do agree that the OP is confused on that issue: the definition given in the first paragraph of the post properly requires that $X=Y$, and my answer of course requires that as well, and the whole thing makes no sense if $X \ne Y$.

Comment: I'll add a comment to that effect in my answer.